# PLSQL DBMS scheduler not getting compiled

Tags: database, oracle, job-scheduling

I am getting:

> ora-01858: a non numeric character was found where a numeric was
>   expected

while trying to execute below script:

```
begin
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
(job_name => 'UK_BANK_BATCH',
job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
job_action      => 'declare 
x varchar2(1000);
y varchar2(1000);
p_month number ;
p_year number ;

begin
SELECT to_number(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,"MM"))into p_month FROM DUAL;
SELECT to_number(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,"YYYY")) into p_year FROM DUAL;
uei.uk_emp_infotypes_pkg.UK_POST_BANKS(x,y,"E",p_month,p_year,"R");
end;',
start_date      => 'sysdate',
repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY',
end_date        => '31-dec-9999',
enabled         => TRUE,
comments        => 'Gather table statistics');
END;
```

Comment: It looks like your strings are surrounded with the double quote character " rather than two single quotes assuming your intention is to escape the single quote.  `start_date` is a timestamp so you should be passing in `sysdate` rather than the string `'sysdate'` (really you should be passing in a timestamp).  Same with `end_date`-- pass in a `date` rather than a string.

Comment: Justin is right. Additionally: `SELECT to_number(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,"MM"))into p_month FROM DUAL` can be simplified to: `p_month := extract(month from sysdate)` (the same for year) which also removes the need to escape those quotes. But you still need to replace `"E"` with `''E''`

Comment: Hi thanks a lot justin and a horese with no name:)
it's working now.just need one more help in knowing what actually happend when double quotes are used instead of single quote.

Comment: And one more hint. If you don't want to use double quotes try this. `v varchar2(50) := q'~ abcd' aaa' dfa' eere  ~';`.  `q'~ -open string ~' - close string.`